# Attribute href not allowed on element span at this point

Tags: валидация

У меня в коде (в главном меню) вкладка прописана так:

```
<li data-id="..." {% if this.isUrlPathIncludePath('/'~ageCategory.slug) %}class="active"{% endif %}>
    <a class="commit-text_font-fam-rb" href="/{{ ageCategory.slug }}" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="name">{{ ageCategory.slug }}<br />
            <span class="commit-text_font-fam-rb">...</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Однако, валидатор на эти строки ругается:

**"Attribute href not allowed on element span at this point."**

```
<li><span class="commit-text_font-fam-rb" href="">
```

То есть, он (валидатор) каким-то образом "у себя в мозгах" обрезает тег ***a***, а ***href***, причем пустой, "присобачивает" к вложенному в него ***span***. Может кто подсказать, как эту ошибку можно поправить?

Comment: У меня ощущение, что проблема кроется в `href="/{{ ageCategory.slug }}"`. Пробовали убрать слэш?

Comment: Мутная тема... а вы пробовали без кода `{{ageCategory.slug}}` скажем в href смотреть как валидатор работает да и какое значение эта, вышеупомянутая конструкция выводит?

Answer (score 0):

Я сам ошибся - привел в вопросе код для вкладки главного меню ПК-версии, а сейчас только понял, что валидатор ругается на верстку мобильного меню, там действительно пункты прописаны:

```
<ul class="...">
    <li {% if this.isUrlPathIncludePath('/'~ageCategory.slug) %}class="active"{% endif %}>
        <span class="commit-text_font-fam-rb" href="">{{ ageCategory.slug }} месяцев</span>
        <ul>
            <li>...
```

...

То есть я сам когда-то заложил эту ошибку).. Сейчас поправим-с.

Вопрос решен, всем добра и простите за отнятое время!)